# How to create a time-series graph from a number I get from API request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, timeserieschart

Lets assume that I run a simple loop that requests a number from an API and prints it every 30 seconds:

```
import requests
from time import sleep

while True: 
    # Get difficulty number:
    stats = requests.get('http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_stats/').json()
    diff = stats['difficulty']
    # Print difficulty number:
    print(diff)
    # Pause for 30 seconds:
    sleep(30)
```

What is the easiest way to get updated time-series graph every 30 seconds, instead of just a number?

Comment: Matplotlib is the best solution for your requirement. If you know JavaScript, there are tons and tons of libraries out there. Cheers

Comment: https://pythonprogramming.net/python-matplotlib-live-updating-graphs/